# Groovy SQL named list parameter

Tags: sql, groovy, named-parameters

I want to use a keyset of a Map as a list parameter in a SQL query:

```
query = "select contentid from content where spaceid = :spaceid and title in (:title)"
sql.eachRow(query, [spaceid: 1234, title: map.keySet().join(',')]) {
    rs ->
        println rs.contentid
}
```

I can use single values but no Sets or Lists.
This is what I've tried so far:

```
map.keySet().join(',')
map.keySet().toListString()
map.keySet().toList()
map.keySet().toString()
```

The map uses Strings as key

```
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Also, I don't get an error. I just get nothing printed like have an empty result set.

Comment: try `[spaceid: 1234, title: "'" + map.keySet().join("','") + "'" ]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appoach will not give the expected result.

Logically you are using a predicate such as

```
 title = 'value1,value2,value3'
```

This is the reason why you get no exception but also no data.

Quick search gives a little evidence, that a mapping of a collections to IN list is possible in Groovy SQL.
Please check [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-5436) and [here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/pull/216)

So very probably you'll have to define the IN list in a proper length and assign the values from your array.

```
 title in (:key1, :key2, :key3)
```

Anyway something like this works fine:

**Data**

```
create table content as 
select 1 contentid, 1 spaceid, 'AAA' title from dual union all
select 2 contentid, 1 spaceid, 'BBB' title from dual union all
select 3 contentid, 2 spaceid, 'AAA' title from dual;
```

**Groovy Script**

```
map['key1'] = 'AAA'
map['key2'] = 'BBB'

query = "select contentid from content where spaceid = :spaceid and title in (${map.keySet().collect{":$it"}.join(',')})"
println query
map['spaceid'] = 1
sql.eachRow(query, map) {
    rs ->
        println rs.contentid
}
```

**Result**

```
select contentid from content where spaceid = :spaceid and title in (:key1,:key2)
1
2
```

The key step is to dynamicall prepare the IN list with proper names of the bind variable using the experssion `map.keySet().collect{":$it"}.join(',')`

**Note**

You may also want to check the size if the map and handle the case where it is greater than 1000, which is an Oracle limitation of a single IN list.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I had to add to remove whitespaces and dashes from the keys in order to make your solution work for me
.replaceAll("\\s","").replaceAll("-","")

Comment: This looks like it's just doing fancy string concatenation, rather than actually using a parameterized SQL statement, so wouldn't this still be vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: Nope @nbrooks this approach uses (dynamicaly created) bind variables. Same concept is used in Hybernate.

Answer (score 0):

It has worked for me with a little adaptation, I've added the map as a second argument.

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName", "userid", "pass")
    Map<String,Long> mapProduitEnDelta = new HashMap<>()
    mapProduitEnDelta['key1'] = 1
    mapProduitEnDelta['key2'] = 2
    mapProduitEnDelta['key3'] = 3
    produits : sql.rows("""select id, reference from Produit where id IN (${mapProduitEnDelta.keySet().collect{":$it"}.join(',')})""",mapProduitEnDelta),
```

Display the 3 products (colums + values from the produit table) of id 1, 2, 3